# What does the dsedit group command do?

Tags: macos, command-line, administrator

what is the role of the below command ? Will it change the user from being admin to a standard ? any files will be corrupted or affected ?

sudo dseditgroup -o edit -d username -t user admin

Answer (score 0):

dseditgroup can do many things, like create and delete groups, add nested groups to an existing group, and check membership of a given user for a given group.

man dseditgroup for more info

Bests,